# What type of motherboards should I use to build a system with 8 Intel Xeon E5520 Processors?

Tags: motherboard

I was given 8 Intel Xeon E5520 processors.  I would like to build a parallel computing system for simulation and data processing.

What type of motherboards should I get to build this system?  It would be great if I could put all of the boards in one case/chassis.

Thanks!

Comment: This is still pretty broad. A few questions: Are you hoping to do this all on 1 board, 4 boards (dual CPU) or 2 boards (quad CPU)? Do you have a chassis picked out? Multiboard cases are rare/expensive.

Comment: Frankly.  I am not sure how this could possibly be too broad.  If I ask for a recommendation for one piece of hardware (mobo) for a specific task (parallel processing)  given a single condition (processor type) what would it take to make the question more specific?